# how to identify feeds in a web crawl?

Tags: java, rss, feed, atom-feed

I've run a web crawl and gathered a lot of html and xml pages. My purpose is to extract all Rss/Atom feeds out of them. I noticed that many sites simply use "text/xml" as content type on the header, so I can't identify a feed from any other kind of xml. So I wrote this piece of code:

```
public boolean isFeed(String content){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
    Elements feed = doc.getElementsByTag("feed");
    Elements channel = doc.getElementsByTag("channel");
    if(feed!=null){
        if(!feed.isEmpty()){
             return true;
        }
    }
    if(channel!=null){
        if(!channel.isEmpty()){
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there anything missing here? Any problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the document using full-blown XML parser. If it doesn't compile, it's not Atom. Then take the document (root) element. If it's not `<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">`, it's not Atom. Of course use appropriate APIs to read tag name and namespace, don't compare strings.

Take similar approach to discover RSS. Or use [Rome](http://rometools.org/) library to parse the document for you.

Comment: What is the root element of RSS feed?

Comment: @Pazis: both RSS and Atom are XML documents. Root element of an XML document is basically the outermost tag (the first XML tag in the file excluding prolog).